# D3 charts - Combine multiple charts togheter

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, charts

First of all, I don't have any code yet, as I'd like to understand if what i'm trying to do it's actually possible or not before even try to code it.

Basically, I'm developing an angularjs application, and I need to display some data into charts.

I say charts, because the data is different and I need to display my data using different chart types (bars, lines, area)

So, my idea was to create a directive structured like this:

```
<my-chart>
 <line-chart data="[data]" ...></line-chart>
 <line-chart data="[data]" ...></line-chart>
 <bar-chart data="[data]" ...></bar-chart>
 <area-chart data="[data]" ...></area-chart>
</my-chart>
```

all the child directives will require the parent directive in order to work.

With this method, I should be able to easily show/hide specific chart based on user selection, but honestly, since I've never developed anything with D3, but i'm learning it now, I don't know if this is even possible or not, or if there's already something that allows my to achieve something like above.

Thanks for any help and sorry if the question is not purely code-related.

Comment: Definitely this is possible!There is already a library which does something similar to what you want to achieve maybe you can have a look https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3

Comment: If you wanna put this as an answer I can select it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already an angular library which does something similar to what you want to achieve.

Demo [here](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/#/quickstart)